# Get single main status from JEST table based on priorities?

Tags: abap, opensql, cds

For each object number in JEST table I want to get a single status that I consider my main status.

The main problem is that some status that in my case I consider unique like I0076 (deletion flag) can be active at the same time than others like created (I0001). In this scenario I would like to use GROUP BY **objnr** and then use a CASE in the status where I0076 always overrides any other status.

Is that possible with ABAP CDS or SQL? Or do I have to write ABAP code (AMDP or post processing) to solve this?

Input:

```
+-------+-------+
| OBJNR | STAT  |
+-------+-------+
| OBJ1  | I0001 |
| OBJ1  | I0076 |
| OBJ2  | I0001 |
+-------+-------+
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------+
| OBJ1  | I0076 |
| OBJ2  | I0001 |
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when there are not just two values for STAT per group but  more, and none of those is the magic status I0076? Is there some general priority?

Comment: @Philipp In my particular case I have a WHERE condition where only 5 status can be selected and I0076 is the only one that can overwrite the others if it exists, since the rest are mutually exculsive (Created, Released, Completed and Closed). But I suspect in the future there may be other magic statuses, that's why I wanted to know if I can use a CASE or something like this with an aggregation or a select distinct

Comment: Should I0076 be selected disregard if it is active or not, or it is always active?

Comment: I0076 can be toggeled. The first time is set, it's added to JEST table with status active, but you can unset it later and the status remains in the table (with INACT = ''). But for this problem I ignored the INACT flag from the JEST table since it's irrelevant for the problem. I will always only select active statuses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your status priority in your CDS view definition with aggregation on `CASE` condition and `COALESCE`. If your statuses are split into two groups of mutually exclusive statuses (say "overriding" and "non-overriding"), then it is enough to have only one `COALESCE` and one `CASE`.

Like this:

```
define view z_demo_v as select from jest {
  OBJNR,
  coalesce(
// Overriding statuses
    max( case when STAT = 'I0076' /*and other overriding values go here*/ then STAT end ),
// Non-overriding statuses. All overriding are captured in previous CASE
//so no need to exclude them here, coalesce will return the first MAX
    max( STAT)
  ) as STAT
}

  where INACT = ''
  group by OBJNR
```

If you can have more than one status in each group, then you can nest as much `coalesce` as you need putting the highest priority statuses first (because in CDS `coalesce` function accepts only two arguments, but in SQL it can have many).

```
define view z_demo_v as select from jest {
  OBJNR,
  coalesce(
    coalesce(
      // Status with highest priority
      max( case STAT when 'I0076' then 'I0076' end ),
      // Status with second-highest priority
      max( case STAT when 'I0070' then 'I0070' end )
    ),
    // Status with other priority (that should be mutually exclusive)
    max( STAT)
  ) as STAT
}

  where INACT = ''
  group by OBJNR
```

Of course, it will need to be updated for new statuses, but because CDS syntax is limited, I do not see lightweight options.

For more robust solution you can create another CDS view which will contain status priority with the structure:

```
| STATUS   | PRIORITY |
| (CHAR 5) | (INT)    |
+----------+----------+
| I0001    | 1        |
| I0011    | 2        |
| I0076    | 100      |
| I0079    | 101      |
```

where each overriding statuses will be placed with higher priority and priority should uniquely identify status. It may be taken from some Z table where you directly put priority or from customizing settings if they are available or from your coded AMDP (for example, substringing last 3 characters and ordering by them via `row_number()` function).

Then you need to have two views joined with that view:

- First view will translate status code to status priority and calculate the most prioritized status: `MAX( PRIORITY ) as FINAL_STATUS`
- Second view will translate it back: FINAL_STATUS -> PRIORITY -> STATUS.

```
define view z_stat_prio_v as select from z_statprio_t {
  STATUS,
  PRIORITY
}

define view z_demo_stat_last_v as select
  from jest as j
  join z_stat_prio_v as p
  on j.stat = p.status
 {
  j.OBJNR,
  max( p.PRIORITY ) as FINAL_STATUS
}

  where j.INACT = ''
  group by j.OBJNR


define view z_demo_stat_v as select
  from z_demo_stat_last_v as s
  join z_stat_prio_v as p
  on s.final_status = p.priority
 {
  s.OBJNR,
  p.STATUS as STAT
}
```

**UPD**: If you always have overriding status (`I0076` in your case) after any general status (`I0001`), then you can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with the same `JEST` table filtered in-place. Below DDL source was successfully activated in SAP_ABA 750 SP 08.

```
define view Z_TEST_V as select from JEST as j1
  left outer join JEST as j2
    on j1.OBJNR = j2.OBJNR
     and j2.STAT = 'I0076'
     and j2.INACT = ''
  {
  j1.OBJNR,
  coalesce (
    j2.STAT,
    j1.STAT
  ) as STAT

}
  where j1.INACT = ''
    and j1.STAT <> 'I0076'
```

Comment: Very nice answer thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't work with my 7.50, but I tested in the SCP trial and it's correct. Since I didn't specify version, I marked it as the good one.

Comment: @RaTiO Please, can you tell what the error did you get?  May be I can find a workaround without that functions

Comment: @RaTiO I've updated the answer without MAX. That code was activated in my BW 7.50

Comment: yes, that LEFT OUTER JOIN made the trick for the 7.50. Thank you very much! I was trying many things with LEFT JOINS and similar but I didn't manage to find your solution. Now it looks quite elegant from my point of view. It's the 3rd time I use coalesce and still I never remember to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using three CDS views.

- In the first CDS view you use a where statement to select only the deleted status (where stat = 'I0076')
- In the second CDS view you use a where statement to select only the non-deleted status (where stat <> 'I0076')
- In the third CDS view you use a left outer join on the first and second view and add a case statement to only include one of the results (case when First.stat is null then Second.stat else First.stat end as status)

Comment: Good answer thanks. I prefer the @astentx solution but yours of course also works and it does in my old 7.50. But I will still try to find some alternative with less DDLs involved